# ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected - exporting data from table to csv

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data from a table in my database to a csv file. I found an example online and tried it but got the following error:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

The code i used is as follows:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "C:\Users\Roshane\myfile.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM Data_admin.Customer;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the filename.

Comment: There is no `into outfile` available in Oracle. Read the manual

Comment: This is a MySQL `select` statement. MySQL is owned by Oracle.

Comment: You can find the answer [`here:`](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/121968/2/).

Comment: @vortex7: MySQL is owned by Oracle, but till a year back, they were owned by completely different companies and followed different development paths. Most features/syntax are different in MySQL Database and Oracle Database. The only syntax that are usually similar are the ones mentioned in the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I read this manual : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/select-into.html, which claims otherwise.

Comment: @eric.itzhak: that is the manual for **MySQL DBMS** which is something completely different than the **Oracle DBMS**.

Answer (score -1):

Like some users have pointed out in the comments, what you provided is not valid Oracle syntax. Here are some ways in which you can export data from oracle to a text file.

1. UTL_FILE (Oracle's in-built package and recommended way to work with files).
2. Spooling to a file (simple, but limited in functionality)

   `sql> spool C:\Users\Roshane\myfile.csv`

   `sql> select customer_name || ',' || customer_id` 
    `sql> from   Data_admin.Customer;`

   `sql> spool off;`
3. If it is a one-time task like sending the data in an excel/csv format in an email, most SQL editors (sql developer, toad) allow you to export data in multiple formats. Just right click on the data grid when you see the results or see if there is a "DATA > EXPORT" option in the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Andrew. How do you get both the listing (<li>) and the {code} tags to work together. I get only get one of them working.